# formatting a string with html for localization in spring

Tags: spring, localization, internationalization, string-formatting

I have a string with urls in them. 
eg: `Under maintenance. <a href="site-url">Try again</a> after sometime`
I want to pass the complete string to the translators.

I see that there are two options
1. `label.maintenance = Under maintenance. {0}Try again{1} after sometime` (pass with anchor tags as variables)
2. `label.maintenance = Under maintenance. <a href="site-url">Try again</a> after sometime` (pass the string with html)

In the first case if the translator misplaces {0} and {1} that may spoil the format of my page.
In the second case, the translator has to understand html and can possibly inject incorrect links.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this problem multiple times before and I came to conclusion that second option is best. Although it requires that translator know what HTML is all about, it turns out it gives the best results.
It communicates clearly what is a link here and if translator needs to re-order the sentence (which happens just too often), (s)he knows what part belongs to link.
In the first example, translator wouldn't know why the sentence contains placeholders and what to do with them. At best (s)he will ask. At worst, translator could re-order them or move translated "Try again" somewhere else and put another word between placeholders.

The conclusion is: leave HTML in translatable resources. At the same time, try to hire experienced software translators as oppose to regular translators. Chances are high they would understand Localization concepts and they would use common glossary of software terms (i.e. the one from Microsoft). That would make your software easier understandable for end users and decrease Localization defects that you will need to fix. In the end hiring software translator may cost less than "cheap" regular one...